# Finding the distance in the two bodies problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am reading the question and solution [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~fratus/phys103/LN/TBP.pdf)

> $$
> \mathbf{R} = \frac{m_1 \mathbf{r}_1 + m_2 \mathbf{r}_2}{m_1+m_2}\tag{4}
> $$
>   $$
> \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2\tag{9}
> $$
>   $$
> \mathbf{r}_1 = \mathbf{R} + \frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\mathbf{r}\,;\qquad\mathbf{r}_2 = \mathbf{R} - \frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}\mathbf{r}\tag{10}
> $$

In equations $(10)$ they say that $r_1$ and $r_2$ can be found by algebraic rearrangement, I can not find how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rearrange eq. (4) to have $\mathbf{r}_1$ on the left

$$ \mathbf{r}_1 = \frac{M\mathbf{R} - m_2 \mathbf{r}_2}{m_1} $$

and then use eq. (9) to substitute for $\mathbf{r}_2 = \mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}$. Then you need to rearrange again to have all $\mathbf{r}_1$ on the left. And do the same for $\mathbf{r}_2$. It's really just simple algebra.